# Unix command - for a particular folder, list users and the size of files including subfolders

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to have the `Unix` command  for listing all the users along with the filesize including sub directories  for a specified folder ie if the specified folder is `/test/kaustav` I would like to know the users and the respective file sizes including sub directories in `/test/kaustav`

I have tried  the below

`ls -l option` ( this does not give me subdirectory information)

`ls -lR` ( when i direct the output to a file, the output is very messy)

any help here will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So how would you like the output to appear?

Comment: And what OS are you using?

Comment: Do want a single list of the contents of `/test/kaustav` with owners and sizes including subdirectories, or do you want a *recursive* list that simply shows each file at every directory depth?

Comment: mark -- i would want a single list of the contents of /test/kaustav with owners and sizes including subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

If your files/directories don't have special characters (like spaces) in their names, you could use

```
ls -l `find . -type f`
```

`.` is directory where you want it to start from (current directory, in given example)

Comment: If this is the solution, why not just `find . -type f -ls` ?

Comment: find . -type f -ls  ..... this does not work . Not getting an error but the script just keeps on running

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want the file size along with its owner:
You can do:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c " %U %s %n"
```

which will show recursively from the current directory: owner filesize file.
You can also sort it on file size and still show owner and file:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c " %U %s %n" | sort -n -k 2,2
```

EDIT:

So you want to get the directory sizes, but you don't want to print recursively?

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -I {} -0 sh -c "stat -c %U \"{}\"; du -s \"{}\"" | awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1' | sort -n -k 2,2
```

If you do want to get owner and size recursively, then just remove -maxdepth 1. It is unclear when you tell "including sub directories" if you want this for the filesize only or for the listing.

Comment: this again gives an exhaustive list... ls -l works fine but when it comes to directories it just gives 4096 or some number less than 4096... is there a way i can have directory size along with ls -l option

Comment: Emilen thanks for trying this out....yes you have got me correct ie i would like to print the owner and the filesizes for every file and directories inside the folder /kaustav/test... i am getting syntax error while trying out the above command (Unexpected EOF while looking for matching '""'). Pardon me for my limited knowldge in unix but i am hoping to get there

Comment: Emilen --i guess this works... i am guessing you have displayed the size in Kilobyte.. Please correct me if i am wrong....

Comment: You guessed it right, if you want the size in bytes you can pass the -b option to the du command. Although there is probably a simpler solution than the one I gave, it does work for me so either I miss something or you copy something wrong. I suggest you experiment with the 'du' command which allows to recursively get the size of directories (for instance just try `du -b -s *`) and don't forget `man du` for help !